# want to be able to do the post method and display the data in the table field

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, django

currently when i submit the function first takes me to the api page where i have to click on post again for the results to update in the database then click on back button and refresh the page to see the updated data, it will be nice if the reduce button could update and display the data on the table without redirecting to the api page. Thank You, Please Help. trying to render the data here

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def sRd(request, pk):
    sw = get_object_or_404(Swimmers,id=pk)  # gets just one record
    current_sessions = sw.sessions + 10
    sw.sessions = current_sessions  # updates just the one in memory field for sw (for the one record)
    sw.save()  # you may want to do this to commit the new value
    serializer = SubSerializer(instance=sw, data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return JsonResponse(data=serializer.errors, safe=False, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Want to render the data here on this page:

```
return render(request, 'accounts/modals/swimming/_vw_table.html', {'sw': sw})
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use Ajax asynchronous to be able to process data on the backend and display the results on the frontend using jQuery or any of the frontend framework. You must also include a csrf token or exempt it using @csrf_token by adding the plugin

from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // CSRF TOKEN //
    function getCookie(name) {
        let cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
            const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }
    const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

//Post Button Working With View Function sRd
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#post-form").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            headers: {
            'Content-type':'application/json',
            'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
          },
            url: "{% url 'srd' srd.pk %}",
            type: "POST",
            data: $('#post-form').serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        }); // end ajax
    });
});
</script>
```